# Clone rows based on the column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have data like shown below:

```
ID  Duration  Start Date          End Date
------------------------------------------------------
10  2         2013-09-03 05:00:00 2013-09-03 05:02:00
```

I need output like below:

```
10  2        2013-09-03 05:00:00 2013-09-03 05:01:00  1  
10  2        2013-09-03 05:01:00 2013-09-03 05:02:00  2
```

Based on the column `Duration`, if the value is `2`, I need rows to be duplicated twice.

And if we see at the Output for `Start Date` and `End Date` time should be changed accordingly.

And `Row count` as an additional column for number rows duplicated in this case 1 / 2 shown above will help a lot.

And if duration is 0 and 1 then do nothing , only when duration > 1 then duplicate rows.
And at last Additional column for number row Sequence 1 , 2 ,3 for showing how many rows was duplicated.

Comment: Can you not achieve this with a stored procedure?

Comment: I'm Newbie to SQL Help needed Please :)

Comment: This is rather challenging if you're new :)

Comment: I can solve this challenge, if some can help out.

Comment: What is the longest duration ?

Comment: Duration is dynamic from the source, it may be 0 - 100 . If Duration is 0 and 1 then do nothing , only when > 1 then duplicate rows

Comment: Here Key Column is "RESOURCE_HOST_ID"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the sql below, I added some comments where I thought it was seemed necessery.

```
declare @table  table(Id integer not null, Duration int not null, StartDate datetime, EndDate datetime)

insert into @table values (10,2, '2013-09-03 05:00:00', '2013-09-03 05:02:00')
insert into @table values (11,3, '2013-09-04 05:00:00', '2013-09-04 05:03:00')



;WITH 
 numbers AS (
--this is the number series generator 
--(limited to 1000, you can change that to whatever you need
-- max possible duration in your case).
    SELECT 1 AS num
    UNION ALL
    SELECT num+1 FROM numbers WHERE num+1<=100
)
SELECT t.Id
    , t.Duration
    , StartDate = DATEADD(MINUTE, IsNull(Num,1) - 1, t.StartDate)
    , EndDate = DATEADD(MINUTE, IsNull(Num,1), t.StartDate)
    , N.num
FROM @table t
LEFT JOIN numbers N
    ON t.Duration >= N.Num
-- join it with numbers generator for Duration times
ORDER BY t.Id
    , N.Num
```

Comment: Thank you so much hazimdikenli !. Its Working great  as per my requirement . Really Appreciate you Help :) :)

Comment: hazimdikenli can you please explain me in detail on this condition                            "t.Duration >= N.Num"

Comment: Duration is how many times you want it repeated, so it will match numbers that is equal or less than the Duration, i.e. 1..Duration

Comment: @max please mark it as answer, if you think this is the answer.

Comment: @ hazimdikenli how to about having new column like Duration_New showing values for duration in one minute resolution instead of sum of duration ?
Example:
id  Duration_New .....
10 1
10 1
11 1
11 1
11 1

Comment: I'm getting same data like duration column using below function 
DATEDIFF(mi,EndDate,StartDate) as Duration_New

Answer (score 0):

This works better when Duration = 0:

```
declare @table  table(Id integer not null, Duration int not null, StartDate datetime, EndDate datetime)

insert into @table values (10,2, '2013-09-03 05:00:00', '2013-09-03 05:02:00')
insert into @table values (11,3, '2013-09-04 05:00:00', '2013-09-04 05:03:00')
insert into @table values (12,0, '2013-09-04 05:00:00', '2013-09-04 05:03:00')
insert into @table values (13,1, '2013-09-04 05:00:00', '2013-09-04 05:03:00')
;WITH 
 numbers AS (
--this is the number series generator 
--(limited to 1000, you can change that to whatever you need
-- max possible duration in your case).
    SELECT 1 AS num
    UNION ALL
    SELECT num+1 FROM numbers WHERE num+1<=100
)
SELECT 
      Id
    , Duration
    , StartDate
    , EndDate 
    , num
FROM 
(SELECT 
      t.Id
    , t.Duration
    , StartDate = DATEADD(MINUTE, Num - 1, t.StartDate)
    , EndDate = DATEADD(MINUTE, Num, t.StartDate)
    , N.num
FROM @table t
INNER JOIN numbers N
    ON t.Duration >= N.Num ) A
-- join it with numbers generator for Duration times
UNION 
(SELECT 
      t.Id
    , t.Duration
    , StartDate-- = DATEADD(MINUTE, Num - 1, t.StartDate)
    , EndDate --= DATEADD(MINUTE, Num, t.StartDate)
    , 1 AS num
FROM @table t
WHERE Duration = 0)
ORDER BY Id,Num
```

Comment: I edited my original query to handle duration=0 situations.